# How to make code like repmat MATLAB on Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, google-colaboratory

This MATLAB code is from Main_MOHHO.m from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/80776-multi-objective-harris-hawks-optimization-mohho. I want to make the same code using python, but I can't make the `Rabbits` variabel.

```matlab
clc;
clear;
close all;
%% Problem Definition
nVar=3;             % Number of Decision Variables
VarSize=[1 nVar];   % Size of Decision Variables Matrix
VarMin=0;          % Lower Bound of Variables
VarMax=1;          % Upper Bound of Variables
nPop=5;            % Population Size
%% Initialization
empty_Rabbit.Location=[];
empty_Rabbit.Cost=[];
empty_Rabbit.Sol=[];
empty_Rabbit.IsDominated=[];
empty_Rabbit.GridIndex=[];
empty_Rabbit.GridSubIndex=[];
Rabbits=repmat(empty_Rabbit,nPop,1);
for i=1:nPop
    Rabbits(i).Location = rand(VarSize).*(VarMax-VarMin)+VarMin; 
    X(i,:) = rand(VarSize).*(VarMax-VarMin)+VarMin;     
end
```

I try to make it on google colab like this.

```py
import numpy as np
nVar = 3 # Number of Decision Variables
VarSize = np.array((1, nVar)) # Size of Decision Variables Matrix
VarMin = 0 # Lower Bound of Variables
VarMax = 1 # Upper Bound of Variables

nPop = 5 # Population Size
class empty_Rabbit:
  Location = []
  Cost = []
  IsDominated = []
  GridIndex = []
  GridSubIndex = []
  Sol = []

Rabbits = np.tile(empty_Rabbit, (nPop, 1))
X = np.zeros((nPop, nVar))
Rabbit_Location = np.zeros((VarSize))
Rabbit_Energy = math.inf

for i in range(nPop):
  Rabbits[i, 0].Location = np.multiply(np.random.rand(VarSize[0], VarSize[1]), 
                                       (VarMax-VarMin) + VarMin)
  print(Rabbits[i,0].Location)
```

But, the `Rabbits_Location` same for each row.

[Output Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjjtf.png)

What is the correct way to create `Rabbits` variable in python so the output like the output  with number 1 in the pic? Thank you.

Comment: You are repeating your mistakes from the previous question.  You don't know enough python to make effective of a class.  And custom classes aren't useful in numpy arrays.  You can't replicate the matlab `struct` this way.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues exist in your code. First, [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) repeats **the same object** `(nPop, 1)` times. So, when you change one of the objects, you actually change the same memory location. Second, you want to initialize a different object each time instead of referring to the same object, so you want to write `empty_Rabbit()` to create a new instance of that object. Both suggestions can be achieved using a comprehension like `[empty_Rabbit() for i in range(nPop)]` and reshape to any new dimensions if required.

```
import numpy as np
nVar = 3 # Number of Decision Variables
VarSize = np.array((1, nVar)) # Size of Decision Variables Matrix
VarMin = 0 # Lower Bound of Variables
VarMax = 1 # Upper Bound of Variables

nPop = 5 # Population Size
class empty_Rabbit:
  Location = []
  Cost = []
  IsDominated = []
  GridIndex = []
  GridSubIndex = []
  Sol = []

Rabbits = np.array([empty_Rabbit() for i in range(nPop)]).reshape(nPop,1)
X = np.zeros((nPop, nVar))
Rabbit_Location = np.zeros((VarSize))
Rabbit_Energy = np.inf

for i in range(nPop):
  Rabbits[i, 0].Location = np.multiply(np.random.rand(VarSize[0], VarSize[1]), 
                                       (VarMax-VarMin) + VarMin)
  print(Rabbits[i,0].Location)

for i in range(nPop):
  print(Rabbits[i,0].Location)
```

Now, the output of both print statements will be identical with distinct rows:

```
[[0.5392264  0.39375339 0.59483626]]
[[0.53959355 0.91049574 0.58115175]]
[[0.46152304 0.43111977 0.06882631]]
[[0.13693784 0.82075653 0.49488394]]
[[0.06901317 0.34133836 0.91453956]]

[[0.5392264  0.39375339 0.59483626]]
[[0.53959355 0.91049574 0.58115175]]
[[0.46152304 0.43111977 0.06882631]]
[[0.13693784 0.82075653 0.49488394]]
[[0.06901317 0.34133836 0.91453956]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.io.loadmat` uses structured arrays when loading `struct` from MATLAB `.mat` files.  But I think that's too advanced for you.

I think you need to create a set of `numpy` arrays, rather than try for some sort of class or more complicated structure.

```
empty_Rabbit.Location=[];
empty_Rabbit.Cost=[];
empty_Rabbit.Sol=[];
empty_Rabbit.IsDominated=[];
empty_Rabbit.GridIndex=[];
empty_Rabbit.GridSubIndex=[];
```

becomes instead

```
location = np.zeros(nPop)
cost = np.zeros(nPop)
sol = np.zeros(nPop)
isDominated = np.zeros(nPop)     # or bool dtype?
gridIndex = np.zeros(nPop)
gridSubIndex = np.zeros(nPop)
```

`np.zeros` makes a float array; for some of those you might want `np.zeros(nPop, dtype=int)` (if used as index).

```
 rabbit= np.zeros(nPop, dtype=[('location',float), ('cost',float),('sol',float), ....])
```

could be used to make structured array, but you'll need to read more about those.

MATLAB lets you use iteration freely as in

```
for i=1:nPop
    Rabbits(i).Location = rand(VarSize).*(VarMax-VarMin)+VarMin; 
    X(i,:) = rand(VarSize).*(VarMax-VarMin)+VarMin;     
end
```

but that's slow (as it used to be MATLAB before jit compilation).  It's better to use whole array calculations

```
location = np.random.rand(nPop,VarSize) * (VarMax-VarMin)+VarMin
```

will make a (nPop,VarSize) 2d array, not the 1d that `np.zeros(nPop)` created.

Looks like `X` could be created in the same way (without iteration).